# Emailed extent reports doesn't load screenshots

Tags: java, email, extentreports

I am trying to send my extent reports as email. The reports as being sent. The problem is the screenshots in my extent reports is missing in the email. If I open the report in my local device, the screenshot is there.

This is for a Selenium test am doing. I am using extent reports for my logs. I am trying to send my extent reports as email. The reports as being sent. The problem is the screenshots in my extent reports is missing in the email. If I open the report in my local device, the screenshot is there. Below is code of my Listeners.java

```
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;

public class Listeners implements ITestListener {

     protected static WebDriver driver;
     protected static ExtentReports reports;
     public static ExtentTest test;
     Base B = new Base();

    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
          test = reports.startTest(result.getMethod().getMethodName());
          test.log(LogStatus.INFO, result.getMethod().getMethodName() + " test started");
         }


    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
          test.log(LogStatus.PASS, result.getMethod().getMethodName() + " test passed");
         }

    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
          test.log(LogStatus.FAIL, result.getMethod().getMethodName() + " test failed");
          try {
            B.getScreenshot(result.getName());

   String file = 
    test.addScreenCapture("/Users/username/Documents/Eclipse-Workspace/Test/test-output/"+result.getName()+"screenshot.png");
            test.log(LogStatus.FAIL, result.getMethod().getMethodName() + "test failed", file);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
          test.log(LogStatus.SKIP, result.getMethod().getMethodName() + " test skipped");

    }




    public void onStart(ITestContext context) {
        System.out.println("Started");
          driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
         reports = new ExtentReports( "./test-output/Extentreports.html");      
    }

    public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
          driver.close();
          reports.endTest(test);
          reports.flush();

    }

}
```

I expect to view the screenshot taken on test failure when I receive the email. But now I see an empty thumbnail in the emailed extent report.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been raised multiple times in the past. A quick search would have pointed you in the right direction.

The solution is to email the report along with screenshots as a zip file, and ensuring images are saved relatively to the Html file.

Comment: If this question has been raised multiple times in the past, there should be a duplicate. In that case you shouldn't answer, but instead vote to close as duplicate.